# Strange characters appearing when I use the Ctrl and Arrow keys to navigate

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

When I type <kbd>Control</kbd> and any of the arrow keys in any terminal (`gnome-terminal`, as well as `terminator`), I get this (or something like it).

It happens when I use `openbox` as well, so it's not a `compiz` issue. And it's only in terminal programs, never in a GUI app (such as Firefox, Chrom(ium)e, or Empathy).

[image]

Comment: What were you expecting Ctrl+arrows to do in a terminal window?

Comment: what keyboard do you use and what is your keyboard settings?

Comment: @colin ctrl+arrow jumps to the end of the next or previous word

Comment: @Dirk I use the built-in keyboard on my asus 1001p with the 105-key-keyboard settings. Didn't have this issue until last week either.

Comment: @James, weird, I had some issue with my keyboard when I selected a different layout from US, but if these settings has worked before you should probably check for a bug report on [Launchpad](http://launchpad.net)

Comment: @Dirk, that was my first place to look. Haven't found anything yet.

Comment: @Dirk, that may be true in many applications, but I think it's most likely defined in some graphical widget library, and I don't see it defined in the bash(1) documentation, so I wouldn't assume that it works in the shell.  ESC f and ESC b move forward and backward by words in the shell; bash(1)'s documentation on readline explains how to bind different keystrokes if you prefer.

Comment: @Colin, it works by default in gnome-terminal and konsole on both Ubuntu and Fedora so if it's not working for James, I figure it's a bug

Comment: @Dirk @Colin, I'm starting to agree that it's a bug. Going to remove `gnome-terminal` and see if I can get it to reset itself somehow.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

What is in your `~/.inputrc` and `/etc/inputrc`? The minimum to get those keys working is, I think:

```
# mappings for Ctrl-left-arrow and Ctrl-right-arrow for word moving
"\e[1;5C": forward-word
"\e[1;5D": backward-word
"\e[5C": forward-word
"\e[5D": backward-word
"\e\e[C": forward-word
"\e\e[D": backward-word
```

If you have these in `/etc/inputrc`, the file needs to be included from `~/.inputrc`, so check that it has the following line:

```
$include /etc/inputrc
```

Comment: I'm wondering why this is happening in kubuntu 12.10. It's never happened in a previous version before. Is this a bug that needs reporting?

Comment: I had this issue and your comment about including the file in the local ~/.inputrc solved it. It had appeared because I had created and local inputrc without incluing the global one...

Answer (score 0):

You may be using the wrong shell. Try to change the shell into bash by commanding

```
chsh -s /bin/bash $(whoami)
```

Do not use sudo or run as root. You may be prompted to enter the password. Reboot after you change the shell.