# .inputrc `forward-word` + select

Tags: command-line, keyboard, shortcut-keys, inputrc

Following from [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162247/why-does-ctrl-left-arrow-not-skip-words), I added `CTRL+ ←` and `CLTR+ →` functionality to my Ubuntu terminal to skip words by adding to `.inputrc`:

```
"\e[1;5C": forward-word
"\e[1;5D": backward-word
"\e[5C": forward-word
"\e[5D": backward-word
"\e\e[C": forward-word
"\e\e[D": backward-word
```

Now, I would like to skip words *while highlighting them* using: `CTRL+SHIFT+ ←` and `CLTR+SHIFT+ →`. Using `cat`, I see the hotkey should just change from `^[[1;5D` to `^[[1;6D`.

However: **What is the equivalent keyword "`forward-word-select`"?** Better yet -- where can I find a list of such available commands?

Bonus:

While `cat` for `CTRL+Home` gives `^[[1;5H` and `CTRL+End` gives `^[[1;5F`, `CTRL+Shift+Home` and `CTRL+Shift+End` give no output. How can I also add a binding to these key combinations (for similar selection-skip functionality)?

Comment: I don't think `bash` (or `readline`) has this concept of _selecting_ a part of the command – does it? In Midnight Commander, Ctrl+Shift+Left/Right automatically jump by words and select the text; selection here is done by `mc` and not `bash`. Other apps might also have their means of selecting.

Comment: In some terminal emulators (e.g. `xterm`) Ctrl+Shift+Home/End produce the escape sequence you're looking for. In some others (e.g. `gnome-terminal` or other `VTE`-based ones) they move the scrollbar to the top/bottom (that is, the keypress is unavailable for apps running inside), however, produce the said escape sequences on the _alternate screen_ which your shell shouldn't switch to. Other emulators might behave in other different ways.