# List of inputrc keyboard action labels for keyboard operations?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, inputrc

Where do I find a list of the potential keyword operations labels I can attach to various keystrokes, like in this post?

[.inputrc `forward-word` + select](https://askubuntu.com/questions/976441/inputrc-forward-word-select)

In that post I see `forward-word` and `backward-word`.  I need a complete list of those action/operation labels, especially the one for:

- selecting a word forward, like the way Ctrl+Shift+NumPad-right-arrow does on Windows
- selecting a word backward, like the way Ctrl+Shift+NumPad-left-arrow does on Windows

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where can I find documentation for readline?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1024863/where-can-i-find-documentation-for-readline)

Comment: `.inputrc` is for configuring readline