# How do I remove special characters when typing shortcuts in terminal?

Tags: command-line, 18.04, gnome-terminal

I'm on a clean installation of Ubuntu 18.04.

Whenever I type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd><-</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>-></kbd> in terminal ";5D" or ";5C" prints on the line.

Is there a way to set these shortcuts to the next or previous words?

Comment: man and google: readline "key bindings", forward-word and backward-word

Comment: Please check your `/etc/inputrc` file and see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/162247/why-does-ctrl-left-arrow-not-skip-words