# Ubuntu 16.04 command line .inputrc for key binding?

Tags: command-line, bash, shortcut-keys

On my command line in Ubuntu Server 16.04.1 , I would like to bind <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>up/down</kbd> to the bash history incremental search function. I found some posts how to do it. They involve the `~/.bashrc` and `~/.inputrc` files.

[Strange characters appearing when I use the Ctrl and Arrow keys to navigate](https://askubuntu.com/questions/53556/) says this works via the `.inputrc` file in the home directory. [Why does ctrl + left arrow not skip words?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162247/) contains comments about not using `.inputrc`, about using `.zshrc` and using `.bashrc`. I am still too new to not be confused.
I did not have any `.inputrc` in my fresh server install.

I do not understand those things:

- is .inputrc the right place to put in key bindings in 16.04?
- Is that the same for all different flavours als older version of ubunutu?
- it is normal to have no .inputrc file in my home directory?
- What is recommended : copy the /etc/input to home and edit or make a link
  in a new .inputrc and edit the file in etc?

I did not get it to work, too. I tried both copying the file from `etc` and rename it to `.inputrc` and also creating a new file in `~/` with:

```
touch .inputrc
nano .inputrc
```

The file content:

```
$include /etc/inputrc
```

Here is the what I put into the files.

```
# mappings for Ctrl-left-arrow and Ctrl-right-arrow for word moving
"\e[1;5C": forward-word
"\e[1;5D": backward-word
"\e[5C": forward-word
"\e[5D": backward-word
"\e\e[C": forward-word
"\e\e[D": backward-word
# ctrl up,down
"\e\e[A": history-search-backward
"\e\e[B": history-search-forward
```

Both do not work, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key is ignored. <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>Up/down</kbd> do not show the search and <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>left/right</kbd> do not skip words. I think it matches the answer of the seconds post.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. Putting the "mappings for Ctrl-left-arrow and Ctrl-right-arrow for word moving" into my `~/.inputrc` worked for me.

It does *not* work to have those settings in `/etc/inputrc` file.

My `~/.inputrc` file looks like this:

```
# mappings for Ctrl-left-arrow and Ctrl-right-arrow for word moving
"\e[1;5C": forward-word
"\e[1;5D": backward-word
"\e[5C": forward-word
"\e[5D": backward-word
"\e\e[C": forward-word
"\e\e[D": backward-word
```

I deleted the above from the `/etc/inputrc` file, which (in my humble understanding) does not appear to be read by Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Share how did you do it

Comment: updated @MostafaAhangarha

Answer (score 2):

Hy !
Perhaps too late, but I post this for posterity...

Yes, it is normal to have no `.inputrc` in your home. Just create it.
Are you sure you've reloaded the file?

Disconnecting from terminal and reconnecting, or simply use
`bind -f  ~/.inputrc`

That shall do the job...